# Is a question such as 'What to (do) ...?' grammatically correct?

Tags: questions

I'm confused if questions starting with 'What to ...' are grammatically correct or not.  For example:

> What to do if I reached there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"What to do?" is a very informal way of asking "What can I do?" or "What should I do?" or "What is there to do?"  It is sometimes used in [headlines](http://usofsolo.com/dir/2014/08/what-to-do-this-labor-day-weekend/).  It can have connotations of either boredom (if you don't have any idea how to spend your time), or desperation (if you need to fix a bad situation).

"What to do:" is an informal way of saying "Here is what you can do:".  It is often used at the beginning of a list of instructions.

In the original poster's question, "What to do if I reached there?" is probably not the best way to ask the question.  Here are some alternatives, from less formal to more formal:

- What's next?
- I'm here.  Now what?
- What should I do after getting there?

To my (American) ear, "Where to?" sounds natural; "What for?" sounds natural, but should often be replaced by "Why?"; and there are more situations in which "to what?" sounds natural than "what to?" sounds natural.

Here are some questions that are similar to "What to do?".  They are also very informal:

- What to say?  ("What can I say?" is an alternative.)
- What to wear?  ("What should I wear?" is an alternative.)
- [What to be?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120901011418AAXf0u9) ("Which career should I choose?" is an alternative.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, "What to do, what to do?" is something one would be saying when talking to oneself... And I cannot think of any other use of that question. (The similar, informal questions that Jasper lists are also things that would generally be said primarily when talking to oneself, in my experience.) I would never say "What to do if I reached there?" -- I'd say, "What should I do if I got there?" or "What would I do if I got there?" or "What will I do if I get there?" -- or, if I had a specific place in mind, "What would I do if I reached Italy? What will I do if I reach the top of this hill?"

There are titles which *instruct*, using a "What to do" -- "What to do when you're expecting a child," "What to do if your cat is throwing up," etc. -- but those are not *questions*, and are a less pushy way of saying, "What *you should* do when/if..."